# is it correct to say: "global warming is under way"

Tags: word-usage, collocations

dealing with global warming, can I put out that "the global warming/ or global warming is under way?" Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Depending on your perspective, it could be seen as slightly "weaselly" phrasing. As with, say, *The yeti is / Yetis are under threat of extinction*, the strong implication is that yetis (or global warming) ***do in fact exist*** (regardless of whether they're under threat, underway, or whatever).

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I think the question is about the correct use of "underway" not on the merit of being true or not.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, [underway](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/underway) means:

> - Already commenced or initiated; in progress.

(AHD)

From [Early Warning Signs of Global Warming](http://www.ucsusa.org/global_warming/science_and_impacts/impacts/early-warning-signs-of-global.html#.WH-P2vnhBPY):

> - Compelling new evidence demonstrates that ***global warming is already under way***  with consequences that must be faced today as well as tomorrow

From [The Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/uk/sport):

> - A 23-year experiment ***finds surprising global warming impacts already underway***. Some ecosystems are absorbing less carbon, which could ...

From [Global Warming Information Center Fact Sheet](https://www.nationalcenter.org/GWFactSheet.html)

> - Contrary to numerous press reports, there has never been a group of 2,500 scientists claiming that ***human-induced global warming is underway***.

From [Cimate Hot Map](http://www.climatehotmap.org/global-warming-effects/):

> - ***The impacts of global warming are already underway and far reaching***. Explore how global warming is impacting people, oceans, freshwater, ecosystem

Comment: So you would say that global warming has been *initiated*? Is global warming being *carried out* or *put into effect*?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, **underway** is not an ideal word choice there, IMO, but you could get away with using it.

A ship between London and New York may be *underway*, which means that it has begun its journey and is *en route* to its destination. A process may be **underway**, that is, it has been started and is on its way to completion.

But something like global warming, which is a *byproduct* of our consumption of fuels, is unlike a process intentionally begun, not like a journey intentionally embarked upon.

It would be better to say that global warming is *happening now*.

Comment: Can you provide one, I mean just one, reliable source to support your answer?

Comment: Would you say *The lava flow is underway*?  You might, and many people might, but I wouldn't. **underway** is often (mis)used as if it were a synonym for *happening now*, in situations which lack the sense of that which is *intentionally initiated*.

Comment: An eruption can be said to be "underway", I don't know whether it is intentional or not. http://bigthink.com/eruptions/new-undersea-eruption-underway-in-the-northern-mariana-island

Comment: Ruling out out Vulcan's involvement, a volcanic eruption is not intentional.

Comment: I agree with TRomano --  I, personally, wouldn't say global warming is "underway".  It conveys the wrong image.  But if someone else said it I wouldn't argue with their interpretation.

Comment: In addition to being intentionally initiated, there is also the notion of a destination, end, or goal. *The voyage was now underway.  The month-end account reconciliation process is underway and should run to completion in about an hour. The restoration work was underway.*